# Challenges when doing mobile application development with Python

Tags: android, python, ios, mobile, windows-phone

I have been learning programming through  Python over last the  few months and I have covered pretty much all the basics without getting too deep into any one concept.

What I am wondering now is where to go from here, I am mainly  interested in application development on mobile devices.

So:

1. what would be the best language to move to or is there a good reason to stay with python?
2. I have tried Kivy and Python-for-android  and they work well at the basic level I am at right now but  what do the experienced people out there think of the limitations of using  python to develop applications as opposed to using other languages like java etc..?

Comment: It just sucks when questions like these are closed as not constructive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there are two issues which are not easy to overcome for "production grade" mobile application with Python and current mobile ecosystem (iOS, Android)

- Python application start up slowly due to running through long dynamic module import stack. When your application grows complexity you'll essentially hit this wall.
- Python does not integrate well to existing application packagement models, making it always trickier than "pure" native application development. Eventually you need to mix and master both native development and Python development, adding extra complexity for handling the stack.

This is an article I wrote long time ago, but still holds true http://opensourcehacker.com/2008/02/21/building-commercial-grade-mobile-applications-with-python-for-series-60/

Not sure how Windows Phone and IronPython work out together. Or IronPython with MonoTouch or MonoDroid.

There are success stories for JavaScript based application development, like Appcelerator, but those stories have a lot of dollars backing them up to smooth the rough edges http://www.appcelerator.com/developers/

If you don't like Java and Objective-C and would like still to do mobile development on professional level I suggest to take a look on C# and Xamarin tools http://xamarin.com/

Comment: Thanks,  the article was very well written and informative, one of the main reasons I have gotten into programming is to develop for the android platform so is it a no-brainer that I should just learn Java or should I go down the route you suggested of c# to give myself more options?

Comment: If you go C# route your code will be more portable across platforms. If you are not planning to target other platforms forget it. Also, Xamarin tools are commercial and cost €€€.

Comment: one last question, if I were to go down the C# route to make my code more portable as you mentioned, would it in your opinion be easier to go on after and learn Java if needed?

Comment: Learning Java after C# is relative easy and vice versa. After all, Microsof create C€ to be Java's competitor.

Comment: Thanks again  for all the information and the help,it has made my decision much easier, I have started learning  C#.